# mysql LOCK TABLE - no "commit" of data until UNLOCK

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, locking, rollback

I have a curious problem - I have a PHP (5.5.9) script that writes to a MySql (5.6.27) database. The pseudocode looks something like this:

```
LOCK TABLE A WRITE, B WRITE, ... , C WRITE;
-- do some inserts/updates
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

If the script runs successfully then everything is fine. However if I stop the script half-way the operations that are performed are not committed (I am not using transactions).

I am baffled, I thought that there was no transaction-like logic when it comes to LOCK, simply that no other sessions are able to access those tables. Can someone please help me understand what is going on under the hood to prevent data being persisted in this scenario?

Thank you :)

Comment: MySQL automatically rolls back the changes when the client disconnects before releasing the lock.

Comment: Why would it do that, it's not a transaction? Is there any documentation that supports/elaborates on that statement?